# How to losslessly rotate rotate jpeg images *without* a change to the last modified date?

Tags: image-editing

I'm looking for some convenient tool to handle such rotation without changing the file timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any image tools that have this functionality built in, but you can use the built-in UNIX [touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/touch.1.html) command to adjust the timestamps.

1. In Terminal, run `touch -r photo.jpeg timestamp`. That will create an empty file named `timestamp` with the timestamp of your image (replace `photo.jpeg` with the path to your file).
2. Edit your file however you want.
3. In Terminal, run `touch -r timestamp photo.jpeg`. That will copy the timestamp from the `timestamp` file back to your image file.
4. Remove the timestamp file: `rm timestamp`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is hardly convenient

Comment: If you need the workflow simplified, you could put this into an Automator workflow along with an image rotation action.

Answer (score 2):

`for f in *.jpg; do jpegtran -rotate 90 "$f" > "$f.temp"; touch -r "$f" "$f.temp"; mv "$f.temp" "$f"; done`

jpegtran is part of libjpeg. touch -r also changes the creation time if the target time is before it.